# Xcode 7 use jpg files as launch images without warning

Tags: ios, xcode7

In order to reduce the file size of an app I'd like to use jpg launch files instead auf png files.
It is possible to change the file names within the Contents.json in order to use png files. They will show up in the app but Xcode 7 started to show warnings for these files. (Xcode 6 didn't)

How can one suppress these warnings?

Answer (score 1):

In modern versions of Xcode you probably shouldn't be using launch images at all. It's better to use a "Launch Screen File", which is a XIB or Storyboard that shows your launch screen. This way you don't need to create new images every time Apple makes a device with a new screen size.

Comment: that's right - I'm already using a launch storyboard. But it's not available for iOS 7. I need the jpeg launch file feature for iOS 7 support.